# Div has no height even if it has content

Tags: css, html

I have a `<div>` which has some `<img>` in it. Every `<img>` is inside it's own `<div>`. The problem is that the outer div is not automatically taking the height of the content even though I set it's height to auto. Also to display the inner divs inline I set them to `float: left`. But if i remove the float the outer div behaves normally and takes the height of the content. But I need the imgs to be inline. Can anyone help me?

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gEyEr/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="gal-foto">
        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2819/10183644713_c1f49eb81f_b.jpg" class="gal-img">
    </div>
    <div class="gal-foto">
        <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3694/10183642403_0c26d59769_b.jpg" class="gal-img">
    </div>
    <div class="gal-foto">
        <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3764/10183532675_0ce4a0e877_b.jpg" class="gal-img">
    </div>
    <div class="gal-foto">
        <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5331/10183598286_9ab37e273c_b.jpg" class="gal-img">
    </div>
    <div class="gal-foto">
        <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5334/10183535585_04b18fa7da_b.jpg" class="gal-img">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#gallery {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7) inset;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
}
.gal-foto {
    float: left;
    margin: 3px;
    position: relative;
}
.gal-img {
    display: block;
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: See updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gEyEr/6/

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**[See the Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/gEyEr/2/)** . Just add `overflow: auto;` to your main container.

```
#gallery {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7) inset;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: `overflow: auto` worked for me while `clear: both` did not.

Comment: As a further refinement, if it's only the height that should adjust to fit the contents, you can set `overflow-y: auto` specifically, rather than just `overflow`. This way, if you have contents in a grid system, or some other scheme where you don't want horizontal overflow to occur, you can do something different with `overflow-x`

Comment: But why tho????

Answer (score 15):

http://jsfiddle.net/WVL9a/

Add the following:

CSS:

```
.clearer { clear: both; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
    ....
    <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have never understood the clear-fix issues, could you please explain then I'll up vote :) thanks

Comment: Could someone let me know under what circumstances this works?

Comment: @LeeGoddard This explains it better than I will: https://css-tricks.com/clearfix-a-lesson-in-web-development-evolution/

Comment: @BenBarkay - Great site, but I can't see where it says the simple use of `clear: both` ever works alone -- I got the feeling that the fact that doesn't work is the whole point of the page. The end of the article does say this works, though: `  display: flow-root;
`

Answer (score 5):

Add clearfix class to your main container:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
   content: '\0020';
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   visibility: hidden;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

Call it in your main container:

```
<div class="clearfix" id="gallery">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `overflow: auto;` like below:

```
 #gallery {
        border: 1px solid;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7) inset;
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding: 15px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this just write `#gallery` in `overflow:hidden;`

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gEyEr/3/)**

**css**

```
#gallery {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7) inset;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css file :

```
.clear{
clear:both;
}
```

Now, before closing each `div`, add this statement :
`<div class="clear"></div>`

Comment: I added a `<div class="clear"></div>` at the end of the main div and it works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

one method :set `.gal-foto` to `display: inline-block`

or you can clearfix `#gallery`,add these

```
#gallery:after{
   content: " ";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
}
```