# SVG RECT Width and Height of 100%

Tags: svg, background-color, fill, w3c

I am creating an SVG element, and would like to change its background color. As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293026/default-background-color-of-svg-root-element), and as per [W3C recommendations](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html), `background-color` is not a standard style for SVG, but `fill` must be used instead. However, `fill` does not work and [the most common solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293026/default-background-color-of-svg-root-element#11293812) was to create a `rect` element inside the `svg` element and make that rect element have a width and height similar to that of the `svg`.

So, the following is the outcome of the suggested solution:

```
<svg width="300" height="200">
    <rect width="300" height="200" style="fill: rgb(0, 255, 0);></rect>
</svg>
```

I then changed that to:

```
<svg width="300" height="200">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill: rgb(0, 255, 0);"></rect>
</svg>
```

(note that I have `width` and `height` set to 100% in my second attempt).

Now my question: even though this works, is using percentages in width and height a W3C standard? Or is it a hack?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> is using percentages in width and height a W3C standard?

Yes.  According to https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html:

> The supported length unit identifiers are: em, ex, px, pt, pc, cm, mm, in, and **percentages**.