# Why my div has height 0?

Tags: html, css

The div banner contains my header and a background image. This div is getting height zero so the backgroung image is not showing up, but the header does.

html:

```
<div class="banner">
        <header class="menu">
            <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
            <nav>
                <ul>            
                    <li><a href="#">Início</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Categorias</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Membros</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </nav>            
        </header>
    </div>
```

css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.banner {
    background: url("../images/banner.jpg");
    height: 70%;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Div has no height even if it has content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354845/div-has-no-height-even-if-it-has-content)

Comment: None of the solutions given worked for me

Comment: try `html { height: 100% }`

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.banner {
    background: url("../images/banner.jpg");
    height: 70%;
}
```

try to change `100%` -> `100vh`

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your image url..

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.banner {
  background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif");
  height: 70%;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ulpfMb8op4acZQYTRIgv?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

get height by window.onload

```
<div id="header" class="banner">
    <header id="h" class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="../img/a.jpg"></a>
        <nav>
            <ul>            
                <li><a href="#">Início</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Categorias</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Membros</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </nav>            
    </header>
</div>
<script> 
window.onload =function(){
        var header =document.getElementById('h');
        alert(header.clientHeight); 
}
```